# Ajax script doesn't detect an XML when it takes too long

Tags: ajax

I am doing a project with arduino using a web page. When the web starts appears a "loading" gif while it receives an XML file for loading values. This loading gif appears due to an onload event that calls an ajax script. The problem is that if the XML file takes too long to be sent and received the loading gif doesn't disappear. This seems to be something that also occured with other ajax scripts, if they wait for a response for too long they don't execute the rest of the code.

Can you explain me why?

Thanks!!